# How to pass datetime parameter to a condition method?

Tags: c#, datetime

I'm studying object oriented programming. I have a class `Dob`, it reads the date of birth from main. If the date of birth from main was from 10 years ago until now, it says "error", else "verify". 
Here is my class

```
public DateTime _Dob;
private DateTime dob {
 get {
  return _Dob;
 }
 set {
  _Dob = value;
 }
}


public Student(DateTime dob_) {
 _Dob = dob;
}

public void checkdob(DateTime dob) {

 DateTime local = DateTime.Now;
 if (dob.Year >= local.Year - 10)) {
 Console.WriteLine("error");
} else {
 Console.WriteLine("verify");
}
```

Now I want to pass the birth date from main but I don't know how to do that. Here is what I have in main (It has errors and I don't know how to solve it):

```
Student dob = new Student(new DateTime(23/02/2010));
dob.checkdob( 02/12/2010);

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: `new DateTime(23/02/2010)` => this should be `new DateTime(2010, 02, 23)` or `DateTime.ParseExact("23/02/2010", "dd/MM/yyyy")`. See [DateTime constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, you have the `property` just the wrong way around. The idea is that you expose the value of a private field through a public property, not the other way around:

```
private DateTime _dob;
public DateTime Dob
{
    get { return _dob; }
    set { _dob = value; }
}
```

But if you do not use the public property anyway, don't expose it.

Now, it seems strange to pass the date to the constructor of your class, and then pass it again when you want to check it. Use the value you already have.

```
    public void CheckDdob()
    {
        if (_dob.Year >= DateTime.Now.Year -10))
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("error"); 
        }
        else
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("verify"); 
        }
    }
```

Then, to create a new `DateTime` for your constructor, just use the following:

```
Student dob = new Student(new DateTime(2010, 02, 23));
```

And finally, you may want to review your logic, because you do *not* actually check correctly if a date is more than 10 years ago. Then again, what you have *may* fit your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a proper constructor parameter for `DateTime`. There are plenty of them listed [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx).

You can start with using this one,

```
new DateTime(2010,02,23)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an example on how to solve this:

```
using System;

public class Student
{
    public Student(string name, DateTime dateOfBirth)
    {
        Name = name;
        DateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
    }

    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; private set; }
}

public static class Helpers
{
    public static bool IsOlderThen(this DateTime date, TimeSpan age)
    {
        var now = DateTime.UtcNow;

        return now - date > age;
    }
}   

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var adult = TimeSpan.FromDays(365 * 18);
        var studentOld = new Student("Alice", DateTime.Parse("1998/04/17"));
        var studentYoung = new Student("Bob", DateTime.Parse("2015/04/17"));

        Console.WriteLine("isAdult: " + studentOld.DateOfBirth.IsOlderThen(adult));
        Console.WriteLine("isAdult: " + studentYoung.DateOfBirth.IsOlderThen(adult));
    }
}
```